# Want a dense subset of a Sobolev-Bochner space!!

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain.

Let $$W=\{ u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(U))\cap L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(U)) : u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))\}$$ and let 
$$D=\{u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(U)) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(U)) : u' \in L^2(0,T;L^2(U))\}.$$

Is it possible that $D$ is dense in $W$ with respect to the norm
$$\lVert u \rVert = \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H^1)} + \lVert u' \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1})}?$$

How about with the the $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$ norm included above too?

Comment: I want an icecream